# Which one is correct?

Tags: function

The function should sum the elements of the list until the sum is greater than 9000. When this happens, the function should return the sum. If the sum of all of the elements is never greater than 9000, the function should return total sum of all the elements. If the list is empty, the function should return 0.

---

I have written the following codes:

```py
# Write your function here - Coding 1
def over_nine_thousand(lst):
  sum = 0
  for index in lst:
    sum += index
    if sum < 9000:
      continue
    else:
      return sum
print(over_nine_thousand([8000, 900, 120, 5000]))
```

OUTPUT: 9020

However, the program prompted: over_nine_thousand([8000, 900]) should have returned 8900, and it returned None

But the program would accpet the following code as "correct".

```py
# #Write your function here - Coding 2
def over_nine_thousand(lst):
  sum = 0
  for index in lst:
    sum += index
    if sum > 9000:
      break
  return sum
print(over_nine_thousand([8000, 900, 120, 5000]))
```

## OUTPUT: 9020

Both Coding 1 & 2 produce the same results.  It seems to me that Coding 1 is not "correct".

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Also tag your coding language properly.

Comment: Note that it's just "code", not "codes", like "rice" and not "rices".

Comment: The first example should say `if sum >= 9000` with `>=` in place of `>`. Otherwise it's off-by-one from the second example. And, the statement `over_nine_thousand([8000, 900]) should have returned 8900` is plainly false for either example.

Comment: you know the answer. The one that returns the wrong answer(s) is not correct

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those questions that one can answer by mentally going through your own code step by step. Take your code 1, call it with the list [8000, 900]. Note that the function continues to run until the sum reaches 9000. It never will with the list [8000, 900] because that list sums up to 8900 only. So your code never reaches the point where anything is returned to the calling line, and that's why the return value is `None`. Call it with a list that sums up to 9000 or more, and you'll get the correct result (but it's still cumbersomely written).

Comment: Yeah, I know that.  But is Coding 1 wrong?  Or considered bad coding.

Comment: Both return the same output: 9020.

Comment: The way youhave described the assignment, code 1 is wrong. It does not return the sum if the sum is below 9000, as required by the assignment,